# Круговой SVG Прогресс бар

Tags: svg

Есть прогресс бар

```html
<svg width=200 height=200>
      <circle cy=100 cx=100 r=80 fill=transparent stroke="black" stroke-width="20"></circle>
      <circle cy=100 cx=100 r=80 fill=transparent stroke="orange" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="100, 1000"  stroke-dashoffset=0></circle>
</svg>
```

Как сделать чтобы оранжевая полоса начиналась свержу с центра окружности.
Не могу понять? что значит атрибут `stroke-dasharray`, точнее  значения в нем

**100** - это длина оранжевой полоски

**1000** - растояние между такими полосками

В чем измеряется данная величина и как сделать точку отсчета именно сверху?

Да, и как можно эту оранжевую полосу анимировать?

Answer (score 3):

```html
<svg style="height: 250px;">
        <style>
            .st0{
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для Firefox */
                -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для IE */
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
                -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для Opera */
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
            }
        </style>
  <circle cy=100 cx=100 r=80 fill=transparent stroke="black" stroke-width="20"></circle>
  <circle class="st0" cy=100 cx=-100 r=80 fill=transparent stroke="orange" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="20%,1000"  stroke-dashoffset=0></circle>
</svg>
```

С начало обясню автору что такое `stroke-dasharray`:

Управляет видом пунктирной обводки. Можно задавать в единицах длины или в процентах.
Если задано одно значение, второе значение считается равным первому.

Подробно о всех свойствах рассказано [здесь](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-fill-and-stroke/#stroke-dasharray).

А это пример который хотел автор:

```html
<svg style="height: 250px;">
        <style>
            .st0{
                stroke-miterlimit: 5;
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для Firefox */
                -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для IE */
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
                -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Для Opera */
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
            }
            .st0 {
                stroke-dasharray: 1000;
                stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
                animation: dash 7s linear forwards;
            }

            @keyframes dash {
                from{
                    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
                }
                to {
                  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                }
            }
            
        </style>
  <circle cy=100 cx=100 r=80 fill=transparent stroke="black" stroke-width="20"></circle>
  <circle class="st0" cy=100 cx=-100 r=80 fill=transparent stroke="orange" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="100, 500"  stroke-dashoffset=0></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: без анимации приведите пример, когда заполнено 10% круга

Comment: что значит в единицах длины - в пикселях?

Comment: 2ПR, радиус у меня в пикселях, значит длина тоже получается в px?

Comment: @ruslik Обновил ответ.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan по-моему это 5%

Comment: @Alex78191 На глаз увидели?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan да, на глаз https://i.imgur.com/cqafIl5.png

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но так и не понял что значит единица длины
Почему точка отсчета идет с правого края окружности и нужно поворачивать круг,

Comment: @ruslik ответы на все ваши вопросы вы можете найти тут. https://svg-art.ru/

Comment: Вижу кучки чёрного из-под рыжего.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это пример автора, и ему нужно было то что в ответа, Извините но здесь дело было не в дизайне.

Comment: а из за чего эти куски, вроде круги обинаковые по радиусу

Answer (score 2):

По сути `stroke-dasharray` может содержать несколько значения `10,20,30...`, где четными по порядку будут идти длины заполненных линий и нечетными - длины промежутков. После окончания - все повторяется. Все, что вам надо - это задать длину прогресса и максимальную длину без длины прогресса (чтобы избавиться от повторения), на подложке первым должен быть 0 (длина заполненной), потом - длина пустоты равная длинне прогресса и снова максимальную длину без длины прогресса.

```js
function setProgress(elementId, val) {
  let el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  let backProgressEl = el.children[0];
  let progressEl = el.children[1];
  let maxLength = backProgressEl.getTotalLength();
  let progressLength = maxLength * val;
  backProgressEl.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', '0,' + progressLength  + ',' + (maxLength  - progressLength));
  progressEl.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', progressLength + ',' + (maxLength  - progressLength));
}

setProgress('progressBar', .3);

setTimeout(function() {
  setProgress('progressBar', .8);
}, 2000);
```

```css
circle {
  transition: stroke-dasharray 1s;
}
```

```html
<svg id="progressBar" width=200 height=200>
    <circle cy=100 cx=100 r=80 fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="0,0,1000" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"></circle>
    <circle class="progress" cy=100 cx=100 r=80 fill="transparent" stroke="orange" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="0,1000" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61656/discussion-on-answer-by-ags17--svg--).