# Как сделать такой элемент в верстке?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

Как сделать такой элемент статичным.
Но в будущем, чтобы через стили я мог менять длину у синей полоски. К примеру, когда будет 20 мест,  я мог бы поставить 50% длины и синяя полоска заполняла лишь половину длины окружности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где-то был на SO такой вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/683876/275019 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784190/275019 . Ещё где-то на просторах ruSO был прямо такой-же как у вас. Ищите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще есть спец плагины типа Chart.js но на css можно так сделать

```css
.item{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:150px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.item span{
  position: relative;
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:900;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  z-index:100;
}

.item:before{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:conic-gradient(transparent 10%, lightblue 11%);
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.item:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:140px;
  height:140px;
  background:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span>20</span>
</div>
```